# Count of user who respond for a exam in a specific course

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

#### **What I want :**

I'm trying to create a very special count within the creation of a table.
So, There are users who follow courses. In those courses, there are many problems (exams) ==> I want to know how many users have submitted an answer to a problem.

#### **What I have :**

I already fetch the number of users who have answered for the first time (they can answer as many time as they want) to a problem. So I can display the average grade for the first answer.

#### **Example :**

So, let's say, for the first time they answer to the problem A, here is the dispersion :

- 5 users will get the grade 0 for the Problem A
- 15 users will get the grade 20 for the Problem A
- 10 users will get the grade 40 for the Problem A
- 25 users will get the grade 60 for the Problem A
- 5 users will get the grade 80 for the Problem A
- 5 users will get the grade 100 for the Problem A

So here, in my code, I would like to display a new column containing 65 (sum of the user) for every row of the Problem A. And So one for every problem...

So far, this is what I have done :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS First_Attempt_Problem_Grades_Wesh;
CREATE TABLE First_Attempt_Problem_Grades_Wesh (
  UserID VARCHAR(255),
  problemID VARCHAR(255),
  First_Grade INT UNSIGNED,
  Platform VARCHAR(20),
  DataPackageID VARCHAR(255),
  NStudent_Per_DataPackageId INT UNSIGNED,
  INDEX (UserID)
);

INSERT INTO First_Attempt_Problem_Grades_Wesh
SELECT
  x.AccountUserID as UserID, 
  x.ProblemID,
  x.Grade as First_Grade,
  'Wesh' AS Platform,
  x.DataPackageID,
  NStudent_Per_DataPackageId
FROM wesh_problem_events_with_info x
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
      DISTINCT p.AccountUserID,
      p.ProblemID,
      MIN(p.Timestamp) as First_time,
      COUNT(p.AccountUserID) as NStudent_Per_DataPackageId
    FROM wesh_problem_events_with_info p
    GROUP BY p.AccountUserID, p.ProblemID)  t
  ON x.AccountUserID = t.AccountUserID AND x.ProblemID = t.ProblemID AND x.Timestamp = t.First_time
WHERE x.Grade IS NOT NULL
```

But with this table, the number that I get in the column "NStudent_Per_DataPackageId" are wrong ... As you can see :

[image: Result of this query]

Indeed, the problem 1NLpP is mentioned 3 times in the bottom of the image, and the number returned is 1... How can I achieve this query properly?

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because most people don't want to read your complete code.

Comment: Thx @Hille for your welcoming. I have tried to improve my post as much as I could. I hope this is more a MCVE now :)